# How to move data across layers (MVC5 + EF6 + DDD)?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, domain-driven-design

We have a MVC 5 application using DDD principles. I need to send data from the Base Controller to the Base Repository, so I can log what user executed an operation for auditing purposes. The application structure is: Presentation (MVC 5) > Application (AppService) > Domain (Service) > Infra (Repository). The idea is to keep each layer independent from the other as much as possible.

In the BaseController I have the logged user from the session, that is accessible to all classes in the presentation layer:

```
    public ProfileApp ProfileApp
    {
        get { return Session?[Constantes.Session.PROFILE] == null ? CreateProfileApp() : (ProfileApp)Session[Constantes.Session.PROFILE]; }
        set { Session[Constantes.Session.PROFILE] = value; }
    }
```

How can I get that information to the repository, in the Add method, declared as below:

```
public class RepositoryBase<TEntity> : IDisposable, IRepositoryBase<TEntity> where TEntity : BaseIdentity
{
    protected VGPartnerDBContext _Db;
    protected DbSet<TEntity> _DbSet;

    public RepositoryBase(VGPartnerDBContext p_VGPartnerDBContext)
    {
        _Db = p_VGPartnerDBContext;
        _DbSet = _Db.Set<TEntity>();
    }

    protected virtual T Add<T>(T obj) where T: BaseIdentity
    {

        return _Db.Set<T>().Add(obj);
    }
    
    public virtual TEntity Add(TEntity obj)
    {
        return Add<TEntity>(obj);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to do the following, From you controller or Application layer you need to transfer and store data in DB right? In that case you need to create an base DTO

```
    class AuditableDto
{
    public string Username { get; set; }

    public string ModifedBy { get; set; }

    public DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }
}
```

And same for your Auditable entities you need a base class like this.

```
    class AuditableEntity
{
    public string Username { get; set; }

    public string ModifedBy { get; set; }

    public DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }
}
```

And then you can for each request from UI to you action methods in controller make a generic filter to add in your AuditableDtos this metada that you need and in same way you propogate this information to the Entities. In DDD you should follow principle of Persistence Ignorance and Infrastructure ignorance, all layer shoud depend on Domain layer.